# How to select a nested element in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This may be a simple thing but I'm struggling on how to target an element on a click event. I got it working with jQuery but I want to do it in pure JavaScript. Basically I have this list:

```
  <ul class= 'my-todo-list'>
     <li id="todo-1" class="todo">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
     </li>
     <li id="todo-2" class="todo">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
     </li>
     <li id="todo-3" class="todo">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

and my JavaScript looks like this:

```
 document.querySelector('.todo a.delete').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    
    var listElement = this.parentNode.parentElement;
    var todoId = listElement.getAttribute('id').replace('todo-','');
    alert(todoId);
 });
```

What I want is if I click on a delete link I should see the id for the todo. For example if I click on the second delete link I should alert "todo-2".

Note: I tried `document.querySelector('.todo a.delete')` but it didn't work either.

The easy solution with jQuery is

```
 $('.todo a.delete').live('click', function(){......})
```

But I want to do it in pure JavaScript. How can I do that?

Comment: You are adding event listener to only first "delete" link. To add it to every one, you should use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`, and then loop through all of them to attach the listeners.

Comment: Try `querySelectorAll()` to select **all** the `a.delete` elements and add the event listener on each. Alternately, add a single event listener on the `<ul>` and use event delegation

Comment: @Luka yes I = tried querySelectorAll but no luck :(

Comment: @Phil Yes I tried querySelectorAll but it doesn't work. Can you provide a solution please? Thanks

Comment: @Phil I tried this:  document.querySelectorAll('.todo a.delete')

Comment: @Phil I just updated it

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.todo a.delete')` just selects elements. What did you do with the result? How did you attach the event listeners?

Comment: @Phil I attached it to the click event. Please see my Javascript code on my question. Thanks

Comment: There is no code in your question using `querySelectorAll()`. Only [one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764615/how-to-select-a-nested-element-in-pure-javascript#comment109250286_61764615) and you **do not show what you're doing with the result**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an event listener on the `ul` element and check if the element that triggered the click event contains the `delete` class. If it does, get the `id` attribute from the `li` element wrapping that particular element which triggered the event

```js
const $ul = document.querySelector('ul');

$ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('a.delete')) {
    const li = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    const id = li.getAttribute('id');
    alert(id);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
     <li id="todo-1" class="todo">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
     </li>
     <li id="todo-2" class="todo">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
     </li>
     <li id="todo-3" class="todo">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: You can also use `e.target.closest('li.todo')` to get the `<li>` in a more robust way

Comment: @Phil it surely does. Didn't know about this `matches` function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and `map` to map event as

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.todo a.delete')].map((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    var listElement = this.parentNode.parentElement;
    var todoId = listElement.getAttribute('id').replace('todo-','');
    alert(todoId);
    })
 });
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.todo a.delete')].map((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    var listElement = this.parentNode.parentElement;
    var todoId = listElement.getAttribute('id').replace('todo-','');
    alert(todoId);
    })
 });
```

```html
<ul class= 'my-todo-list'>
     <li id="todo-1" class="todo">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
     </li>
     <li id="todo-2" class="todo">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
     </li>
     <li id="todo-3" class="todo">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Why `[...document.querySelectorAll('.todo a.delete')].map()` and not simply `document.querySelectorAll('.todo a.delete').forEach()`?

Comment: Even `Array.prototype.forEach()` is a better fit for this since you're not _mapping_ anything

Answer (score 0):

Using the event target might not work sometimes when there is not a propagation.
Here is a script that I made and it works 100% with all browsers and easy to use too:

(`It works even with dynamic elements just like jQuery`)

```js
// Advanced custom dynamic real time event handler listener supported 100% cross-browsers
String.prototype.addRTListener = function(events, renderingFunction){
    let selectors = this.toString();
    events = events.trim().split(' ');
    for(let even of events){
        even = even.trim();
        if(even.length>0){
            switch(even){
                case "focus":
                    even = "focusin";
                break;
                case "blur":
                    even = "focusout";
                break;
            }
            document.addEventListener(even, function(e){
                const path = e.path;
                document.querySelectorAll(selectors).forEach(function(element){
                    for(let target of path){
                        if( target == element ){
                            if( renderingFunction && typeof renderingFunction == "function" ){
                                renderingFunction(target, e);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                return;
            });
        }
    }
    
}
```

```html
<button id="testBtn">Click Me</button>

<script>

// We can add DOMContentLoaded eventListener just in case our script loads after the DOM other wise you could always load your script before and it should work just like a charm
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

  // it supports multiple events too
  "#testBtn".addRTListener('focus dblclick', (target, e)=>{
    console.log( target ); 
  });
  
});

</script>
```